# Как получить данные с акселерометра телефона на python?

Tags: python, android, мобильная-разработка

У меня есть программа для телефона и компьютера. Она подключена к сокету для обмена данными. Мне нужно получить данные с акселерометра телефона (Android). Сколько смотрел - нашёл только способ с библиотекой android, но скачать её не получается и проверить не могу. Есть ли ещё способы. Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Для программирования под андроид используйте pydroid3

Comment: Хорошо, а как получить данные?

Comment: https://pyjnius.readthedocs.io/en/stable/android.html#accelerometer-access